# Facebook UIActionLinks on Facebook app elements

Tags: facebook

I'm currently developing a Facebook app and I came across a "weird" client request. The app itself is pretty simple. The user can write a story. This story is then saved into a custom database and then displayed on the app's front page along with all the other stories. The request from the client is that we - for each story - implement the "standard" Facebook links which normally go beneath a Facebook wall post (Like, comment, timing). Is this possible and if yes, how on earth....?

I've been reading a great deal about the new custom Actionlinks which can be applied to an app - but this seems more like custom functionality and not the basic Facebook functionality. It also seems like there are no Comment and timing....

Well any answer is much appreciated - also if the answer is: Go with the normal Social plugin LIKE/SEND/COMMENT functions :-)

Thanks very much

/Jan